# Offsetting header rows using ListHeaderRows

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I have a macro that pulls data from a column in another workbook. Both the source and the target workbooks have variable row counts, and columns in either of them can move around at any point, so the columns are matched based on header names rather than column indexes.

The problem that I'm having is that the header row in my target worksheet keeps getting overwritten by the macro and replaced with the header name from the source worksheet. So for example if the target column is called "Supplier" I don't want it to get overwritten by the source worksheets column that is named "Vendor". I have tried implementing the ListHeaderRows functionality with no success, can anyone tell me what's wrong with this code?

Hint: the header rows begin on row 2, not row 1.

```
Set g = target_sheet.Rows(2).Find(what:="Supplier", _
                            lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)

If Not g Is Nothing Then

 Set mainVendorCol = g.EntireColumn
 lHeadersRows = mainVendorCol.ListHeaderRows
 If lheaderrows > 0 Then
    Set mainVendorCol = mainVendorCol.Resize(mainVendorCol.Rows.Count - lHeadersRows)
    Set mainVendorCol = mainVendorCol.Offset(2)
 End If
Set ran = mainVendorCol

For Each c In ran.Cells

    id = c.EntireRow.Cells(3).Value

    If Len(id) > 0 Then

        r = Application.Match(id, srcIdCol, 0)

        If Not IsError(r) Then
            c.Value = Application.Index(srcVendorCol, r, 1)
        Else
            c.Value = "PROJECT NOT FOUND"
        End If
    End If
Next c
```

End Sub

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa175678(v=office.11).aspx  This link suggests a more complete way of identifying the header rows which may be of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I do it. It may seem a little long winded at first but once you're set up there's very little maintenance and you can use it in all your projects.

I have a Class Module called cColumn:

```
Option Explicit

Private msHeader As String
Private miNumber As Integer

Public Property Get Header() As String

    Header = msHeader

End Property

Public Property Let Header(ByVal sHeader As String)

    msHeader = sHeader

End Property

Public Property Get Number() As Integer

    Number = miNumber

End Property

Public Property Let Number(ByVal iNumber As Integer)

    miNumber = iNumber

End Property
```

I instantiate this class in a procdure:

```
    Dim colMainInfoColumns As Collection
    Dim avarMainInfoColumnsToFind() As Variant

    'this is a list of columns I want to find, you could also use an array:
    avarMainInfoColumnsToFind = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Columns") _
            .Range("rgnMainInfoColumnsToFind").Value 

    Set colMainInfoColumns = ColumnBuilder(wksMainInfo, avarMainInfoColumnsToFind)

    If colMainInfoColumns Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
```

I use this function (you can put this in your class module if you want) to create the collection of columns - this looks at row 1, either amend to row 2 or create a new parameter for the row number.

```
    Private Function ColumnBuilder(wksToSearch As Worksheet, avarColumnsToFind() As Variant) As Collection
'---loops a worksheet and creates collection of columns---
'---collection key = column name without spaces---

    Dim colColumns As Collection, clsColumn As cColumn, iIndex As Integer
    Dim iColfound As Integer, sError As String

    Set colColumns = New Collection

    For iIndex = LBound(avarColumnsToFind, 1) To UBound(avarColumnsToFind, 1)

        On Error Resume Next
        iColfound = wksToSearch.Rows(1).Find(what:=avarColumnsToFind(iIndex, 1), lookat:=xlWhole).Column
        On Error GoTo 0

        If iColfound > 0 Then

            Set clsColumn = New cColumn
            clsColumn.Header = avarColumnsToFind(iIndex, 1)
            clsColumn.Number = iColfound

            colColumns.add clsColumn, ConvertStringToKey(avarColumnsToFind(iIndex, 1))

        Else
            sError = sError & vbNewLine & avarColumnsToFind(iIndex, 1)
        End If

    Next

    If sError = "" Then
        Set ColumnBuilder = colColumns
    Else
        Set ColumnBuilder = Nothing
        MsgBox "Unable to process script as the following columns were not found on " & wksToSearch.Name & ":" _
             & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & sError
    End If

End Function

Private Function ConvertStringToKey(ByVal sKey As Variant)

    sKey = Replace(sKey, " ", "")

    ConvertStringToKey = sKey

End Function
```

You can then access your columns by key without spaces, eg:

Returns col number of the "Tenant Reference" column:

```
colMainInfoColumns.Item("TenantReference").Number
```

Counts number of populated cells in the "Tenant Referance" column:

```
WorksheetFunction.CountA(activesheet.Columns(colMainInfoColumns.Item("TenantReference").Number))
```

Comment: jmdon - Thank you very much for your detailed response. I know that you answered this a long time ago and I am way late on this, but this seems to be the exact kind of solution I need. I have 2 questions that I'm wondering if you could answer for me. 1.) in your second block of code, I don't see anything that references the class module that you say is named cColumns and 2.) Where are the last 2 lines of code that reference the keys coming in to play? Is that supposed to be a part of a stand alone function? Any input would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You won't need to reference cColumn in the second block there as that's referenced in the ColumnBuilder function, which is called by the second block. The last two lines are just examples. #1: how to return the column number. #2: how to count the number of populated cells in a column. You can use these anywhere in your code providing you have   first populated the colMainInfoColumns collection by calling the ColumnBuilder. Let me know if you still get stuck!